# Word for outgoing quotation (selling an item)

Tags: word-request, difference

I am struggling to find a word that summarizes a quotation sent from a company to a client. In our current workplace, we have to distinguish between a quote we receive from a supplier and a quote we create for a client.

Would there perhaps be a word that distinguishes them both? The best I've come up with in my limited vocabulary is "Quote to Supply" for outgoing quotes and "Quote to Purchase" for incoming quotes.

Comment: In securities trading, a quote indicating the price at which you'd like to sell is called an *offer*, and a quote indicating the price at which you'd like to buy is a *bid*.

Comment: If nothing else that is more technical is posted here, *supplier-quote* and *client-quote* will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your original question of whether there's a word that distinguishes them both, the answer is no. The definitions of words that would work such as bid, offer, quote, and proposal are all vague enough that they won't delineate cleanly.

That being said, the comments of your original question are excellent suggestions. Offer and bid are already used in securities jargon to mean "a quote to sell something I own" and "a quote for a price I'd pay for something I don't currently own", respectively. The suggestion of agglutination (supplier-quote and client-quote), however, is also a good one.

The decision will lie with you whether you are more interested in brevity or in accuracy and/or descriptiveness. Bid and offer are smaller words, but they have expansive definitions and might be misinterpreted (or worse, transposed). Supplier-Quote and Client-Quote (or variants such as SupplyQuote/ClientQuote or IncomingQuote/OutgoingQuote) are far larger, but more much more descriptive and thus more difficult to misinterpret.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. In terms of bid and offer, we also deal with tenders so these, although great wording, will not suit the quoting section. We were originally thinking of outgoing and incoming quote, however we were hoping there would be a specific word to summarise those. We will be using Supplier Quote and Client Quote for now. Thank you all again.